# Using Neo4J with Mongo DB without replicating entire database

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, laravel, neo4j

I have been working with relational database system (MySQL), MongoDB & Dynamo DB so far and just been introduced to the concept of Graph DB.

I wanted to have database system where I should be able to use

- MySQL for transactional and relational operations (Authentication, Role based accessibility & Financial operations)
- Neo4J for relevancy of content, real time relational queries
- MongoDB for Read Only pre formed JSON objects

Let's take an e-commerce for an example here

I will be capturing all the data in mysql so I can recreate it later in other db systems with concrete fixed relations, will link products and categories, subcategories and users shopping preferences in neo4j. While I want products description in multiple languages which I want to store in MongoDB.

I am no database expert but someone I know who is database admin for quite some time recommended me to not to load up neo4j with such a content which will not be used for forming relation queries, e.g. text descriptions of products and their translations.

I wanted to achieve something like, Neo4J product node will have info which can be used in query (Not a search operation) will have following labels

- Product ID
- Created Date
- Product Title
- Average View Count
- Average Rating

And keep its all text data in Mongo DB.

Doing all this programatically is achievable but I am not sure how much it would affect the performance and how stable would it be. What do you guys suggest?

My objectives are

- Not to create huge copies of same data in multiple db systems.
- Make Databases as optimised for better performance as possible by not loading huge text data in nodes.

Language I am going to use is PHP / Laravel Framework.

**Thanks**

Comment: This talk should give some insights - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50ifNtFAUXg

Comment: Thanks Bajal, I have been through this video, very informative, but it is inclined more towards replicating / migrating mongo to neo4j. I am more interested in retrieving the info from mongo based on result of queries ran in neo4j.

Comment: I like the idea! Have you considered a solution close to what we have with Scout/Algolia? I am even willing to help building something opensource if you are interested.